# SQL Partition Check

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In Microsoft SQL, suppose there are two columns `c1` and `c2`. How does one check whether `c2` partitions or is a function of `c1`?

By `c2` partitioning or being a function of `c1`, I mean rows with distinct `c2` attributes can not have the same `c1` attribute. In the same vein, I would like to extract the rows with the same `c1` attribute but distinct `c2` attributes.

I can certainly construct sets of rows where each set is the collection of rows with an arbitrarily given `c2` attribute. Then we check if all the n(n-1)/2 intersections are empty.

Instead of the kind of cumbersome code described by the last paragraph, is there a short line of code that can accomplish this?

Below I show two examples. In the left table `c2` is a function of `c1` while `c2` is not a function of c1 in the right table.

[image: Example]

Comment: please show some sample data and the expected result

Comment: @vkp: I added an example as you requested.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the issue that is not mentioned here is that SQL SERVER does not support **DISTINCT** within analytic functions.

Error:
**Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.**

---

```
select      c1
           ,c2

from       (select      c1
                       ,c2
                       ,min (c2) over (partition by c1) as min_c2
                       ,max (c2) over (partition by c1) as max_c2

            from        t
            ) t

where       min_c2 <> max_c2
;
```

---

```
c1  c2
2   1
2   2
4   2
4   3
```

Additional solution, just for the fun of it:

```
select      c1
           ,c2

from       (select      c1
                       ,c2
                       ,count (*) over (partition by c1)    as c2_val

            from       (select      distinct

                                    c1
                                   ,c2

                        from        t2
                        ) t
            ) t

where       c2_val > 1
;
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. However, it resolves not the general case but the special one where the values of c2 are all real numbers. Please see my answer and the explanation.

Comment: @Hans, **min** and **max** functions exist for very basic types including numeric types, date and  time types and  character types.

Comment: You mean all values are ordered lexicographically according to the order of ASCII, right? If that is true, I retract my point regarding generality. Do you agree with my point of speed difference since your code has to compute twice (min and max each with complexity O(n)) while mine counts once (with complexity O(n))?

Comment: @Hans, but my solution returns the right results :-) You do not have guarantee that c2 value doesn't repeat more than once for the same c1 value.

Comment: Good point. I added **distinct()** function --- I suppose this is the correct usage, I do not have an SQL application right now --- to exclude the case you mentioned. However, in that case, the complexity for both solutions are about the same. Mine is faster only when we know in advance all the rows are distinct. Do you agree?

Comment: Not yet. I will do it tomorrow when I have access to an SQL software.

Comment: @Hans, in the meantime, please read my answer again. Top part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126710/discussion-between-hans-and-dudu-markovitz).

Answer (score 1):

If we know in advance that the rows are all distinct, we have

```
select c1, c2
from 
    (select c1, c2, count(distinct(c2)) over (partition by c1) as count
    from table) table1
where count>1
```

If we do not know the distinctness of all the rows, the code would be

```
select c1, c2
from 
    (select c1, c2, count(c2) over (partition by c1) as count
    from 
        (select distinct c1,c2
         from table0
        ) table 
     ) table
where count>1
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, you are right. I have corrected my solution. Thank you.